# Intellij idea 2022.1.3 ultimate showing error java: JPS incremental annotation processing is disabled

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, groovy, junit

I am using 2022.1.3 ultimate version and while running groovy test cases I am getting this error

> java: JPS incremental annotation processing is disabled. Compilation
> results on partial recompilation may be inaccurate. Use build process
> "jps.track.ap.dependencies" VM flag to enable/disable incremental
> annotation processing environment.

Due to this error even running a single test takes lot of time. I have tried adding following option in shared build process VM options and also in run configuration but that is not helping.

```
-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false
```

Is anyone else noticing this same issue ?

Original question, How to run a single groovy test case from a large project ?

Comment: if your project uses lombok, this might help https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2842. Also updating Lombok might help

Comment: You should specify -Djps.track.ap.dependencies=true` to enable incremental annotation processing. Note that this may lead to incompatible build results. See [these links](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258659/Vertx-CodeGenProcessor-annotation-processor-is-no-longer-working-after-IDEA-upgrade#focus=Comments-27-4620217.0-0) more info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue with intellij 2022 version. This issue occurs due to old lombok version like 1.16.16 or older. Update the lombok version to latest like 1.18.24. This version will resolve the error.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, In my case, upgrading the version of the Lombok package did not work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.26</version>
</dependency>
```

I suspect the cache problem or something, I use the invalid cache under the file and restart it several times, but it doesn’t work.

Finally, the build runner turns on the delegate ide build/run actions to maven, and that's it. However, after it is turned on, it will be very slow when I run the project debug locally, and then turn it off again. Lombok did not report an error, so it was solved.

[image]